# Finding Matched Cell Values of Multiple Columns and Sending Mail about Matched Info

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have an Excel file with different columns as below (Name, Role, Email). I want to search roles (from Role column) which are repeated more than once, and display the corresponding Values (from the Name column). Finally a mail should be sent about role info to corresponding mail IDs (mentioned in the Email column). Need VBScript approach on same.

```
Name     Role    Email
Ram(z123)MC_PLM_Team Architect (TA), MC_PLM_Software Developer Sh.ram@abc.com
Shm(Z003)MC_PLM_Chief Product Owner (CPO)       Gh.sham@xyz.com
Arn(z789)MC_SW Developer/Designer ES/HMI/NET       Kh.arun@wxy.com
Ach(z234)MC_PLM_Team Architect (TA), MC_PLM_Software Developer   Ch.Achal@klm.com
```

Comment: SO is not a place where other people write code for you. What have you tried so far (show your code), and what *specific* problem (in your code) do you need help with? If you're so new to VBScript that you can't even try anything yet: please go find a VBScript tutorial first. SO is not a replacement for familiarizing yourself with the language you're using.

Comment: Thanks for Your Inputs. Yes i spent some time Quickly to understand VB Internals. Wrote the script, which address my requirement as first version.

Comment: I strongly encourage you to read about the differences between VBScript and VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for Your Inputs. Yes i spent some time Quickly to understand VB Internals. Wrote the script, which address my requirement. This is my first version of script, which will be enhanced further.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    intRows = Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    intCols = Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

    For i = 12 To intRows
     resName = Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value
     primRole = Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 31).Value
     emailID = Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 49).Value

     If resName <> "" Then
        MsgBox resName & vbNewLine & primRole & vbNewLine & emailID
     End If

    Next

    Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set outMail = outApp.CreateItem(0)

    strBody = "Dear XYZ" & vbNewLine & "email from outlook" & vbNewLine & "Best Regards," & vbNewLine & "XYZ"
'   
    outMail.To = "sh.ram@abc.com"
    outMail.CC = ""
    outMail.BCC = ""
    outMail.Subject = "Subject Test VBA"
    outMail.Body = strBody
    outMail.Send

    Set outMail = Nothing
    Set outApp = Nothing


End Sub
```